# Animation when moving to another nib

Tags: iphone, objective-c, presentmodalviewcontroller

i Use this code to move from one class to another. I don't use UINavBarController. Can i use another animation when i change th nib ?

```
 FormViewController *formViewController =[[FormViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"FormViewController" bundle:nil];
formViewController.userImage=imageFb;
[self presentModalViewController:formViewController animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the method

- [-transitionFromViewController:toViewController:duration:options:animations:completion:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-DontLinkElementID_67)

If you are supporting less than iOS 5, you can look at these methods:

- [-presentModalViewController:animated:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-DontLinkElementID_59)
- [-modalTransitionStyle (property)](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-DontLinkElementID_20)

Comment: i can send argument with this ? imageFb in my exemple ? there is not an example please? I am  beginning. And its written "Availability

Available in iOS 5.0 and later."

Comment: You aren't developing for iOS 5?

Comment: i want my application workinkg I want my application running on both ios 4 and 5. This is not the ideal?

Comment: I added some info on supporting less than iOS 5. you have less flexibility with your controller, but hopefully there is a transition there that you would like.